# How to avoid ID Generation Concurrency in JPA 2.0 + Spring 3.0?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

In my web application, I get the `Concurrency Problem` in JPA ID Generation.
I use `Table` generation strategy. I already get [Concurrency Issue](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Concurrency_and_Deadlocks) of JPA ID Generation.

How can I avoid `Concurrency Problem` in JPA ID Generation?
What will be better way for ID generation?
Does Spring 3.0 have a way to avoid it?

Actually, I worry about the database dependency if I use other id generation strategy.

Comment: What database? Unless you utilize a client-side ID generation scheme, your solution will necessarily be somewhat database dependent. With Oracle you can invoke a stored-proc (very messy with JPA/Hibernate) that uses a self-contained transaction.

Comment: @kabram, the application can use Oracle and MSSQL database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EclipseLink will normally use a separate transaction for allocating generated ids.  If you use a JTA DataSource then it cannot, unless you also provide a non-jta-datasource in your persistence.xml.

Also if you trigger a database transaction early (such as a flush) then table id generation will have to use the transactional connection unless you specify a sequence connection pool.

See,
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_connection_pool_sequence.htm#BABIDAGH

Comment: Also ensure you are using a large preallocation size to avoid frequent access to the sequence table.

Comment: I use 20 for preallocation size. Do I need to configure `<property name="eclipselink.connection-pool.sequence" value="1" />` in `persistence.xml` for same transaction of allocation id?

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you can use autonomous transaction and create a stored-proc as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETAPPLICATIONSEQUENCE (
name IN VARCHAR,
offSet IN NUMBER,
seqValue OUT INTEGER
)
AS PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    SELECT sequence_value INTO seqValue FROM sequence_table WHERE sequence_name = name FOR UPDATE;
    UPDATE sequence_table SET sequence_value = sequence_value + offSet WHERE sequence_name = name;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Now as long as you are able to call this stored-proc from within your database code, you can pass in the name of the sequence you want and offset (to get multiple values in one chunk) and get sequence values. You will have to see if SQL Server has an equivalent to AUTONOMOUS transactions.

Answer (score 1):

As that link says, some JPA providers use a separate connection for things like value generation ([DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org) certainly does). So this sidesteps the issue. Depends on your JPA provider (which you don't state).

Answer (score 0):

Then you shouldn't depend on a database to generate your IDs. You can use `UUID` as your key. They can be generated independently of each other, so you won't run into concurrency issues. However you probably would have to change your database schema to support it, because the 128 bits of a UUID might not fit into your current primary key columns.